# Using a reference dataframe to assign categories based on variable names in another data frame in R

Tags: merge, match

I have a data frame where I have assigned categories according to variable names. For eg:

**Name       Category**
Green         1
Red           2
Blue          3

I then want to use this information to populate a new column in a much larger separate data frame with this category. See below for an e.g. of the desired outcome:
**
Name.    Number.     Tx.     Area.   Category**
Green     22         Y       19888       1
Red       97         N       72765       2

Im not sure where to begin, thanks in advance!